# How can I stop the hook from breaking the login/logout function?

Tags: functions, hooks, theme-options

I added this code to my functions file so there are different theme options depending on whether or not a plugin is activated.

```
function theme_options_select() {
if( is_plugin_active( 'gallery-nails/gallery-nails.php' )) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/theme-options/nails/theme-options.php';
}
else {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/theme-options/default/theme-options.php';
}
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'theme_options_select' );
```

I've tried plugin_loaded and setup_theme but then the theme options are inaccessible. init works as well but also breaks the login.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If this is in `functions.php`, then you don't need a hook for this at all, because the `functions.php` file is [loaded right where you want it](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/65c1468ff51eaff16aebfd7a5ab30bfc1fb7c58b/wp-settings.php#L421). So just unwrap this and move it out of a function call altogether; i.e., still in your `functions.php`, but not attached to any specific hook.

Or, use the [`after_setup_theme`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/65c1468ff51eaff16aebfd7a5ab30bfc1fb7c58b/wp-settings.php#L434) hook if you want to delay it slightly.

Comment: Thanks. Tried both those solutions but I get a HTTP ERROR 500 with both. Works fine on xampp though.

Comment: A 500 error is usually indicative of a PHP error. So finding the underlying PHP error would be most helpful. Otherwise there's no way to know exactly why it did not work. It could be something very simple.

Comment: Just commented out the code in the theme-options.php files and tested and they seem to be ok. Must be something in the functions.php file I guess. Tried so many ways to write that code but it just doesn't work for me.